Why doesn’t Get-Partition return *ALL* partitions on my system
I have a Server 2022 box with a lot of attached storage (>100 disks, some are attached via a RAID Card, some via USB and some to SATA ports on the motherboard). Most of the volumes on partitions that are on the drives are access via mount points instead of drive letters. When I run Get-Partition in Powershell, I only get a subset of the partitions on the system. Does anyone know why this is the case? I need Get-Partition because this contains the AccessPaths property. My goal is to associate a Win32_Volume to the specific disk the volume resides on. Thanks!
From the MS documentation, it says Get-Partition will return all partitions on all disks.  On my system, it does not.
update It appears Get-Partition only works with Basic disks and not Dynamic and so the partitions on my Dynamic disks are not showing up.  Is there a workaround to this?  I looked into Win32 class but AccessPaths is not available there…

have you looked at any other class such as Win32_DiskPartition? Get-CimInstance Win32_DiskPartition. You may have to chain commands or pass them to one another to get the exact output you're after

Not too sure why it has issues with dynamic disks, although Get-Volume (MSFT_Volume) seem to return everything, where Get-Partition (MSFT_Parition) does not. I've always used get-volume seems it shows the disk usage, where get-partition does not :/.
# 4 Ways of getting Volume info:
# Slow - Would need to use "Invoke-Command" or "-CIMSession (New-CimSession -ComputerName $Computername" on remote machines.
$part = get-partition -CimSession (New-CimSession -ComputerName $COMPUTERNAME)
$vol = Get-Volume
# Fast - must specify the namespace (Same one Get-Volume uses. You can check with $vol.CimClass)
$WMIStorage = Get-WmiObject   -Namespace Root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage -Class MSFT_Volume -ComputerName $COMPUTERNAME
$CIMStorage = Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage -Class MSFT_Volume -ComputerName $COMPUTERNAME
# All 4 have the accesspath info.
$part.AccessPaths 
$vol.path
$WMIStorage.Path
$CIMStorage.Path
# Native Logical Disk doesnt appear to have path :(
$WMIVol = gwmi win32_logicaldisk


Thank you.  Unfortunately, these other methods don't return DiskNumber which is what I need.  My goal is to get the disk number that a particular Mount Point/volume resides on.  On my system, these volumes are on dynamic disks.  Get-Partition returns both, but sadly, doesn't return dynamic disks.
